# Select2: Infinite Scroll Scrolling Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

A bit of an unorthodox request. I am trying to have infinite scrolling done for a uniquely large (5-25k result set). Select2 on it's own breaks/locks on IE9&10.

Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/33174942 I have been able to implement basic functionality for infinite scrolling.

However, When selecting an item in the non scrolled set you are always returned to the top of the list, but when selecting an item in the paged set it will select and focus that item.

I have made modifications to start at the selected page (also various filtering changes) however I cannot see a way to load prepend onto this list.

Current Code:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    PageSelect: function (Attribute, Value, DefaultValue) {
        var that = this;
        DefaultValue = typeof DefaultValue !== 'undefined' ? DefaultValue : -1;
        $.fn.select2.amd.require(
            ['select2/data/array', 'select2/utils'],
            function (ArrayData, Utils) {
                function CustomData($element, options) {
                    CustomData.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
                }

                function contains(str1, str2) {
                    return new RegExp(str2, "i").test(str1);
                }

                Utils.Extend(CustomData, ArrayData);

                CustomData.prototype.query = function (params, callback) {
                    if (!("page" in params)) {
                        params.page = Math.ceil((that.prop('selectedIndex') + 1) / 50); //Originally and Functionally  = 1
                    }
                    var pageSize = 50;
                    var attrValue = DefaultValue;
                    var results = this.$element.children().map(function (i, elem) {
                        attrValue = elem.getAttribute(Attribute)
                        if (Attribute == null || Value == "-1" || attrValue == Value || attrValue == DefaultValue)
                            if (contains(elem.innerText || elem.textContent, params.term)) {
                                return {
                                    id: elem.value,
                                    text: elem.innerText || elem.textContent
                                };
                            }
                    });
                    callback({
                        results: results.slice((params.page - 1) * pageSize, params.page * pageSize),
                        pagination: {
                            more: results.length >= params.page * pageSize
                        }
                    });
                };
                return that.select2({
                    ajax: {},
                    width: "100%",
                    dataAdapter: CustomData
                });

            });
    }
    });
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question... having 5-25k html elements in same page will break most browsers on "not so high end" systems. If you know you will have this kind of numbers and you want a smooth experience for users in browsers I suggest to split the results somehow. If that content is not designed to be shown in browsers or to be shown only for a few users with high end computers ignore this comment :).

Comment: Agreed but no other currently approved method, though hoping to move to dynamic search and view filter

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this ? Facing the same issue