# Select2 v4.0.0 Performance Issue

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select, jquery-select2

Ive been experiencing performance issues with a large number of items in IE when using the select2 drop down adapter. It looks like this is not a new issue to select2 and people have gotten through it in the past (i.e. here [Select2 performance for large set of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041058/select2-performance-for-large-set-of-items))

However, by looking through the source it seems like the support for the solution linked above has been deprecated in select2 v4.0.0. Have any of you using the select2 v4.0.0 experienced performance issues with large lists (specifically in IE)? If so how did you get through it. Id like to approach the problem with some sort of "pagination" in the drop down like shown in the link above...but it seems like it might be more trouble than its worth. Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can send request to server when using select2 instead of populating it with a lot of unnecessary data AND it's much better for performance.
Here an example:

```
$('#a_tags').select2({
                        placeholder: '',                            
                        allowClear : true,
                        minimumInputLength : 2,

                        ajax : {
                                    url : base_url + 'c_options/you_example',
                                    dataType : 'json',
                                    delay : 250,
                                    data : function(params){
                                        return {
                                                    term : params.term, // search term
                                                    type : 'tags'
                                        };
                                    },
                                    processResults : function(data, page){
                                        dataObj = new Array();
                                        results: $.map(data, function(obj){
                                            c(obj.l_id)
                                            c(obj.l_details)
                                            dataObj.push({
                                                        id : obj.o_id,
                                                        text : obj.o_name_a
                                            });
                                        })
                                        return {
                                            results : dataObj
                                        };
                                    },
                                    cache : true
                        }
            });
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the data i am trying to paginate is local (because of reasons imposed by the dark lord himself). Your comment did spark some ideas however.   I found that the select2 has an adapter called the InfiniteScroll. When used in combination with a custom data decorator (or adapter) it works really well.  The reason you need a custom data decorator (adapter) is because you need to overwrite the query method to return an object that has a "pagination" field in addition to "results" for the callback.  Im not sure if Infinite scroll was meant to be used like this though.

Comment: Here is a JSBin [link](https://jsbin.com/sajufi/edit?html,js,output) showing some of the code. Its essentially a select2v4.0.0.0 wrap of the code in the question mentioned in the my quetion above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041058/select2-performance-for-large-set-of-items