# HTML Select2 with large number of options

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2](https://select2.org/) plugin to enable search in the select tag. I have a large number of options (5000+), and it makes a small delay when the select tag is clicked.

Is there any way to limit the number of items loaded, but should show when the user search.

Note : I use ajax and php to append options.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hav you tried anything on your end?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I had searched over internet for past 2 days and can't understand, from where do I start. I can limit the number of items loaded, but then the search functionality will work only on the loaded options.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041058/select2-performance-for-large-set-of-items if useful for you

Comment: and this one as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533757/select2-v4-how-to-paginate-results-using-ajax

Comment: I am using select2 with ajax as well, and can easily work with millions of options. A proper ajay request will only query for about ten items. When you scroll or search, the old items are destroyed.