# Select2 pagination with local data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using Select2 v4.0.0 and have a list with about 7k+ items. When the user clicks the select it takes few seconds to open the list.

As a solution I tried using pagination with ajax, and works fine. See below for currently using code,

```
$($el).select2({
    ajax: {
        url: _url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 500,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term || '',
                page: params.page || 1
            }
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            var page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.results,
                pagination: {
                    more:(page * 10) <= data.total_count
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

The situation here is that the user can add as many as 'New Lines' and each line have the select2 filed. So a large number of ajax requests are send to server (each time the user searches and also when the item is selected another ajax is request is sent to fetch some other related data) and the server stops responding resulting in error,

> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

So I was forced to stop using AJAX.

I was looking for a solution like here : http://embed.plnkr.co/sUt9zi (I can't get it to work, because it's using select2 v3.4.5).

Is there any similar solutions to make the result paged for data loaded from local variable ? Or any workaround to open the list quicker.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: the example you showed is not using ajax but filters and chunks the local dataset, maybe you should also load all entries once and chunk them for display like in the example link, otherwise you will load the same data over and over again which makes not much sense

Comment: @johnSmith I have tried, I can make it work if I use select2 v3.4.5, but not with v4.0.0

Comment: maybe the answer stating "Here's a working version for Select2 v4" can help you using a custom Data-Adapter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041058/select2-performance-for-large-set-of-items

Comment: @johnSmith It's not for the v4 bro. Its using older version. Using the code with v4 gives me "Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/query" error in console log

Comment: i referred to the answer stating "Here's a working version for Select2 v4" there is no query option there

Comment: I've got the same problem. In my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446920/when-attempting-to-create-a-custom-data-adapter-for-a-select2-combo-box-what-is) there is some sample code.